# Why is first request to Rails 3.2.1 in development mode slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been using Rails 2.x for years, but have just started a new project with 3.2.1. Nothing fancy, just started it with 'rails new projectname'. I've only been working on it for a day or so, so have hardly added anything to the base project.

One weird thing: after making a change to a controller file, say, the next request is very slow... like several seconds. Subsequent requests are lickety split. It's just that first request after a change.

Normal?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.2 actually caches your program and only reloads parts of it when they are changed, to quote the release notes:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/20/rails-3-2-0-faster-dev-mode-routing-explain-queries-tagged-logger-store

> The most noticeable new feature is that development mode got a ton and
>   a half faster. Inspired by Active Reload, we now only reload classes
>   from files you’ve actually changed. The difference is dramatic on a
>   larger application.
>
> Route recognition also got a bunch faster thanks to the new Journey
>   engine and we made linking much faster as well (especially apparent
>   when you’re having 100+ links on a single page).